# Why is this code only selected the top option?

Tags: jquery

Hello I have the following code that is only selecting the first option from my select option list.

Here is what one of the four select list looks like:

```
<select class="attr " id="attr17">
    <option class="attropt" value="">Please select</option>
    <option class="attropt" value="17| " >  (2)</option>
    <option class="attropt" value="17|H" >H (499)</option>
    <option class="attropt" value="17|M" >M (20)</option>
    <option class="attropt" value="17|N" >N (12)</option>
    <option class="attropt" value="17|P" >P (3)</option>
    <option class="attropt" value="17|Q" >Q (24)</option>
    <option class="attropt" value="17|R" >R (116)</option>
    <option class="attropt" value="17|S" >S (50)</option>
    <option class="attropt" value="17|T" >T (367)</option>
    <option class="attropt" value="17|V" >V (534)</option>
    <option class="attropt" value="17|W" >W (476)</option>
    <option class="attropt" value="17|Y" >Y (616)</option>
    <option class="attropt" value="17|Z" >Z (54)</option>
</select>
```

And here is the jquery code that I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("document").ready(function(){

        var link = "http://easytyre123.co.uk/tyres?attr=";
        link += $('#attr13').find(":selected").val();
        link += ".";
        link += $('#attr15').find(":selected").val();
        link += ".";
        link += $("#attr14 option:selected").val();
        link += ".";
        link += $('#attr17').find(":selected").val();

        //$('#sendLink').attr("href", link);

         $("#sendLink").click(function(){
            alert(link);
          });

    });



</script>
<a href="#" id="sendLink">Click to update results and prices</a>
```

When the user clicks on the #sendLink that I want to alert the value of the Link string. However it is always printed out the top value which is empty. Is there any reason why its not selected one that I choose?

Just to clarify if I choose 'H (499)' then the value would still be blank, although im expecting "17|H" to be the returned value.

I am not seeing any errors in the firebug console also.

If there is a much easier way of doing this then I am all ears.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Thought it would be something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you build your string once instead of rebuilding it when the user click. Move the string creation code into the callback :

```
 $("#sendLink").click(function(){
    var link = "http://easytyre123.co.uk/tyres?attr=";
    link += $('#attr13').find(":selected").val();
    link += ".";
    link += $('#attr15').find(":selected").val();
    link += ".";
    link += $("#attr14 option:selected").val();
    link += ".";
    link += $('#attr17').find(":selected").val();
    alert(link);
  });
```

Any reason to use `click` instead of `change` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should do the link when the click occurs:

```
$("#sendLink").click(function(){
        var link = "http://easytyre123.co.uk/tyres?attr=";
    link += $('#attr13').find(":selected").val();
    link += ".";
    link += $('#attr15').find(":selected").val();
    link += ".";
    link += $("#attr14 option:selected").val();
    link += ".";
    link += $('#attr17').find(":selected").val();
        alert(link);
      });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

just do the selected option value capture on `click` event handler instead of doing it in `dom ready`.

like

```
$("#sendLink").click(function(){
   alert($("#attr17 option:selected").val(););
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating sting just once, when the page loads.  The functionl should be called once the user clicks on sendlink.  So, either use onclick event of the button OR use on change event of the dropdowns and create the url.

Also, you need to use $('#attr13').find(":selected").val(); instead of $('#attr13').find(":selected").val();

Thanks.
Hope this helps.